# how to disable background when dialogue box appears

Tags: jquery, html, css

how can ia disable the background and blurr it when my dialogue box is shown
the addClass("blur") is having no effect for the same. warapper is the div containing entire code except for the code for dialogue box

```
<div id="dialog-box" class="dialog-box">

   <form id="dialog-box1"  class="login_form">
    <a href="#" id="close" class="close" style="float:right;margin:8px;margin-top:0px;color:white;text-decoration:none">x</a>
  <h1 style="color:white">Log in</h1>
  <div class="inset">
  <p>
    <label class="label" for="email">EMAIL ADDRESS</label>
    <input class="input" type="text" name="email" id="email">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label class="label" for="password">PASSWORD</label>
    <input class="input" type="password" name="password" id="password">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input class="input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember">
    <label class="label" for="remember">Remember me</label>

       <a href="" ><img class="login_with" src="images/fb.png"></a> 
       <a href="" ><img class="login_with" id="gp" src="images/gp.png"></a>
  </p>
  </div>

  <p class="p-container">
    <span>Forgot password ?</span>
    <input class="input" type="submit" name="go" id="go" value="Log in">
  </p>
  <a href="" style="float:right"><img src="images/fb.png"></a>  <a href="" style="float:right"><img src="images/fb.png"></a>
  <p>

  </p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dialog-box').hide();
  $('#login_button').click(function() {
    $("#dialog-box").addClass('blur');
    $('#dialog-box').show(); 
  });

 $('#close').click(function() {
    $('#dialog-box').hide();
    $('.wrapper').removeClass('blur');
    });
})
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below jquery to create a **model popup** window:

```
function ShowDialog(divID, width, height) {
$("#" + divID).dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    height: height,
    width: width,
    show: "fade",
    hide: "fade",
    modal: true
});
}
```

you have to pass DIV's height, width & title to be shown. Property `modal: true` makes other space unclickable.